# What does "sets free scores" means in this line?

Tags: phrases

After a sudden underwater tremor sets free scores of the prehistoric man-eating fish, an unlikely group of strangers must band together to stopthemselves from becoming fish food for the area's new razor-toothed residents.

Comment: Here *score* means 20, like *dozen* means 12. When Lincoln said "*four score and seven years ago", that amounted to 87 years. The phrase "sets free scores [of fish]" means "many fish were let loose (aka freed)".

Comment: ***Scores*** -  a large number or amount; http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scores

Answer (score 2):

*Sets free scores* is not a unit standing by itself in this sentence. [*Sets free*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/set?q=set+free&searchDictCode=english#set_free) is a verb; and [*scores*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/score#score__12) is a plural noun meaning *many* (a *score* is traditionally twenty).

Thus the tremor releases many fish. Once that has happened, various strangers must band together.